# Basic JS implement basic math to convert a value

Tags: javascript, drupal-7

Before everyone down votes, I have read hundreds of things and still lost as I don't know java at all and all examples found here I have been unable to get to work in my specific instance. I have only got far enough to understand the math I need but not how to apply to existing code I have to fix a problem. So greatly appreciate the help!

I have a value $y that is stored in the db as a number.  I need to do some math to convert it to a percentage. then output it in the markup. Something like:

(number - $y) / number

I just don't know how to code it in properly.

Tried this but no luck...my syntax is not correct

```
$test = percentage = ('800' - $y) / '800';
```

I am also not sure where to place.  I added below where it obtains the $y value from the database, but maybe that is not correct as well.

```
$i = 0;
  foreach ($nodes as $item) {
    $node = node_load($item->nid);
    $node_url = drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.$item->nid);
    $name = check_plain($node->title);
    $field_y = field_get_items('node', $node, 'simplepinitem_y');
    $y = field_view_value('node', $node, 'simplepinitem_y', $field_y[0]);
    $y = check_plain($y['#markup']);
    $test = percentage = ('800' - $y) / '800';
```

In the end i need to call and replace the $y in the output for the display to my calculated value. So that why I thought I needed to create something like $test =  but that clearly is not correct as it errors out.

```
$markers_html .= '<li style="top:' . $test . '%;left:' . $x . 'px" id="simplepinmap-pin-' . $i . '" class="simplepinmap-pins">' . theme('image', $marker) . '</li>';
```

Comment: `Before everyone down votes, I have read hundreds of things and still lost as I don't know java at all .....` You mean Javascript right?

Comment: yes... just an html and css guy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was the percent = being in there. it simply needed to be

```
$test = (calculation);
```

Both ways of calculating work, so posting both calculations in case someone else has the same problem.

The suggested:

```
$leftx = ($x / 788) * 100;
```

But if you need the other side or remainder or percentage. You can use:

```
$leftx = (788 - $y) / 788 * 100;
```

So then where to place in code was correct:

```
$y = field_view_value('node', $node, 'simplepinitem_y', $field_y[0]);
$y = check_plain($y['#markup']);
$topy = (416 - $y) / 416 * 100;
```

THen of course need to change where i wanted to call my new variable $topy

```
   $markers_html .= '<li style="top:' . $topy . '%;left:' . $leftx . '%" id="simplepinmap-pin-' . $i . '" class="simplepinmap-pins">' . theme('image', $marker) . '</li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate a percentage (out of 100) you would use `(number_one / number_two) * 100` as my example below demonstrates.

You should be able to modify that for your code, where `number_one` becomes `$y` and you hard code the rest.

```js
var number_one = 80;
var number_two = 160;

// the variable below calculates "what percentage is 80 of 160"

var percentage = (number_one / number_two) * 100

$('[data-percentage]').text(percentage)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <b>80</b> is <span data-percentage></span>% of <b>160</b>
</div>
```